# Pass values in a textarea and radio input via $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm getting undefined error in IE8 on the a textarea and a radio button when i try to pass them via ajax. i've commented below next to the field that i'm trying to pass over to my send mail php file. i think i just need the right syntax.

this is my jQuery/Ajax code...

```
 var coverletter = $("textarea#coverletter").val();

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'PHPMailer/sendMyform.php',
                             data: { name: $('#name').val(),
                                     from: $('#email').val(),
                                     role: $('#role').val(),
                                     message: $('#coverletter').val(), //textarea
                                     subject: $('#workfor').val() //radio button
                                     //cv: $('#cv').val(),//file upload
                            }
```

i've found some posts on textareas but i dont know hot to work it into the above code

here is the html...

```
        <textarea id="coverletter" class="required"></textarea>

        <input type="radio" name="workfor" value="1" id="company1" class="required">
        <input type="radio" name="workfor" value="2" id="company2" class="required">
```

Comment: `.val()` should work with radio and textarea.

Comment: We need to see the HTML as well, to ensure you have used the right selectors

Answer (score 0):

You radio button selector is wrong:

```
subject: $('#workfor').val()
```

That is looking for an element with the ID 'workfor', which isn't in your html sample.

To get the value of the selected radio button in your html sample you need

```
$("input[name='workfor']:checked").val();
```